# How to add class type list value to another class type list in C#

Tags: c#

I have two class type list with some common properties in both the classes. How can we add one list value to other. I have tried it using foreach loop but I am unable to access second class properties.

```
public class TagViewModel
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagSlug { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagSlug { get; set; }
}
```

using above classes I have created two list

List I

```
List<TagViewModel> list1 = new List<TagViewModel>();
```

List II

```
List<Tag> list2 = new List<Tag>();
```

I have to add value from list2 to list1.

Anyone can help me;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. That's two different types. What you can do is create a new instance of `TagViewModel`, copy all properties from your `Tag` instance and insert the new `TagViewModel` instance into the first list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could abstract the objects to an interface, and then add the interfaces?

```
public interface ITag
{
    int TagId { get; }
    string TagName { get; }
    string TagSlug { get; }
}
```

add the interfaces to your TagViewModel & Tag

```
public class Tag: ITag
{
    ...
}

public class TagViewModel : Tag
{
    ...
}
```

and the create a List of the interface

```
List<ITag> list1 = new List<ITag>();
```

where you can now add ITag interface (so aswell TagViewModel as the Tag)

Afterwards you could check if an item is Tag or TagViewModel with:

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    if (item is TagViewModel) 
    {
    }
    else if (item is Tag) 
    {
    }
    else
    {
        // something else but also at least ITag
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he actually wants them all in the same list. The TagViewModel list will be a representation of all Tags with an added field (and probably an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation for the properties).

Comment: That is a good assumption, but i thought he only asked how he could create a list that can contain both of them :)

Comment: Yes, he did. and the answer is fine for that question, I surely did not downvote it.

Comment: I didn't say nor assume you did :) Although it would be helpful to know why it got downvoted :)